# What does “Optimism keeps us moving forward rather than to the nearest ‘high-rise ledge’” mean?

Tags: meaning

There was the following sentence in Time magazine’s (May 28th) article titled “The Optimism Bias”:

Overly positive assumptions can lead to disastrous miscalculations – make us less likely to get health checkups, apply sunscreen, and more likely to bet the farm on a bad investment. But the (optimistic) bias also protects and inspires us: it keeps us moving forward rather than to the nearest *high-rise ledge*. Without optimism, our ancestors might never have ventured far from their tribes and we might all be cave dwellers, huddling together and dreaming of light and heat.

Does ‘high-rise ledge’ in the above sentence literally mean the ledge or balcony of today’s high-rise building, a steep cliff or rock facing ocean, or something else?

Why is moving forward is better than approaching or facing to ‘the high-rise ledge’? Is there special or negative meaning with “high-rise ledge” used here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suicides often jump from tall buildings: the "high-rise ledge" is a window ledge in a high-rise building, and the sentence is saying that optimism is what keeps us moving forward instead of killing ourselves.

There's a great phrase I first learned from John Irving's [*Hotel New Hampshire*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/034541795X), and which later became a [song by Queen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXF3VD4ASIQ):  "Keep passing the open windows."

Comment: Though it sounds Aesop’s sour grapes, it could be clear to me if the author said straight ‘it keeps us moving forward rather than jumping out of the nearest high-rise window.’

Comment: You have to allow the author a bit of poetic license...  All joking aside, it's possible that the author (or editor) was squeamish about explicitly mentioning suicide - that sort of thing always provokes a strong negative response from the readers (especially of a magazine like TIME).

Comment: I would never have imagined a similar meaning. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the author was thinking of optimism and pessimism. Implying pessimism by suggesting suicide by reference to tall buildings amounts to hyperbole dressed up as euphemism.